# Logo image over menu div like the image

Tags: html, css

im new here and im new in the world of css and html. Im try to edit wordpress template with my custom stlye.

This is my web: http://codigomasivo.com.ar/dev/douglas/
I want to change logo part.

The result where i found is this: http://puu.sh/iMZq4.jpg

I try put logo in "position: absolute;" but when im scroll the page the logo move to down.

Sorry for my english. Im from Argentina. Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  you want your logo to go over the borders of your menu, then you could set a fixed height for your menu like `height: 70px`.

Then for your logo you could use this:

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

I found the code above [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).

Remember to use `z-index: 7000` on your logo, or else the top row will overlap it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a div which contains the actual bar
2. Reduce the actual bar to the height you want
3. Change the new div's backgroung-color to  transparent (`background-color: transparent` )
4. Ensure your logo image has height = new-div-height and the old-bar-div is shorter.

Comment: Hola Andredu, el logo se comporta bien, lo que intento hacer es que sobresalga la parte inferior y superior del logo como muestra la imagen (http://puu.sh/iMZq4.jpg) ves que la parte superior queda sobre el top bar y la de abajo sobre el slide? Eso intento hacer. Gracias

Comment: Please keep language in english as this is an english website. With your spanish part you brought the asking person to speak spanish too and most of the community don't speak spanish so they can't understand you. And this page is not only to help people but also give solutions to the community.

Comment: I've edited the answer with your solution user3763909.

Bish - I'll answer in both languages if it's not an issue. I think it can make the asking user to understand better the solution. Am I beheaving correctly?